# How to set custom model manager as a default model manager in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have multiple apps and models in Django project. Now i want to use custom model manager in all apps models. i don't want to write custom model manager `query` inside of every single model.
I just want to know is that possible to set custom model manager as default models manager for all apps?

**manager.py**

```
class CustomQuerySet(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(CustomQuerySet, self).get_queryset().filter(status=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom manager like this and override the `get_queryset` method or you can add your own methods and filters.

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
 def get_queryset(self):
 return super().get_queryset().filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
 # ...
 objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
 published = PublishedManager() # custom manager.
```

This custom(PublishedManager)manager will allow you to retrieve posts using `Post.published.all().` This will give all the posts having status as published.

This allows you to have two managers `objects`, the default manager and `published`, the custom manager or you can override your default manager like this  `objects = PublishedManager()`

Answer (score 2):

You can set an abstract model and inherit it in all your models,

```py
class MyProjectAbstractModel(models.Model):
   # regular common models fields here
   
   objects = models.Manager() # you can specify the built-in or not, for readbilty I like to do so, you can also set your manager to the objects attribute
   my_custom_manager = CustomQuerySet() # your manager
   class Meta:
      abstract = True # means migrations won't handle this model

class MyModelInAppOne(MyProjectAbstractModel):
   # your implementation...
```